# Calling Azure functions through the Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

Is there a way to call a Azure function through the Azure-CLI? For example with AWS Lambda, Google Cloud Functions and IBM Cloud Functions you can simply use the aws, gcloud, and ibmcloud CLIs to call your functions. This way you don't need to go through the process of getting a URL to test them.

Is this possible with Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage function app with Azure CLI is available, you could get all commands in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#commands).

As for calling the function, it's not provided for now, you could only start or stop the Azure Function App, not the specific function. So if your function is a HTTP trigger function, you could only trigger it with calling the the URL endpoint.

Comment: That is quite unfortunate. Thanks for the help.